# What is the proper way to delete a row from a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have the following code examples:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        [namesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];        
    }   
}
```

and

```
if ([nameSection count] == 0)
{
      [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      [tableView beginUpdates];
      [indexKeys removeObjectAtIndex:section];
      [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Notice the order.... in the first example I am removing the object from my array first, then deleting the row from the tableview.

In the second example I am deleting the row from the tableview, then the section from my array, then the section from the tableview.

Is this the correct order to do things? Or should I be deleting it from the UI first, then the arrays?

The reason I ask is because I am getting some users who are reporting these crashes that I can't seem to repro:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException  - Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1. The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the

with this stack trace:

```
1: libobjc.A.dylib  objc_exception_throw 32
2: CoreFoundation  [NSException raise:format:] 0
3: Foundation  -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] 90
4: UIKit  -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] 6042
5: UIKit  -[UITableView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:updateAction:withRowAnimation:] 254
6: UIKit  -[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] 26
7: Movies  _mh_execute_header 253319
8: UIKit -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] 84
9: CoreFoundation  -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] 52
10: UIKit  -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] 62
```

Comment: Generally you use the first method in modern tableView setups. The second method is a rather older procedural way that will allow you to do multiple things at once.

Comment: [namesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];[tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be updating your data model **first,** else the table view will get confused as to what the correct number of rows and sections is.

Answer (score 3):

After the table is in editing mode, the table view will then ask the data source whether
each row should be editable. If the tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath: method is
implemented, this is called for each row in turn.

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Having established whether a row can be edited, the table view then asks the delegate
which editing style each row should use:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

When the Delete button is tapped, the tableView sends the tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: message to the data source. It takes three parameters:

1) A reference to the tableView itself (in case the data source needs to distinguish between a number of tableViews).

2) The UITableViewCellEditingStyle of the control that’s just been tapped—in this case, UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete

3) An indexPath object locating the row in question.

When the data source receives the commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: message, it needs to do two things:

1) Update the tableView’s model by deleting the object represented by the row in the table. Remember that the table itself is just a view, and unless we actually delete the object from the model, it will reappear in the table the next time the table gets reloaded.

2) Send the tableView:deleteRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation: message to the tableView so that it updates the table display. In this case, because we’re dealing with a Delete, it will animate the deleted cell sliding off to the left, and then move the cells below it up to close the gap.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
   forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            [self.tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
    }
```

There’s a range of table cell insertion and deletion animations to choose from:

1. UITableViewRowAnimationFade - Rows fade in and out.
2. UITableViewRowAnimationRight - Inserted rows slide in from the right; deleted rows slide out to the right.
3. UITableViewRowAnimationLeft - Inserted rows slide in from the left; deleted rows slide out to the left.
4. UITableViewRowAnimationTop - Inserted rows slide down from the bottom of the row above; deleted rows slide up toward the bottom of the row above.
5. UITableViewRowAnimationBottom - Inserted rows slide up from the top of the cell below; deleted rows appear to be covered by the row below sliding up.
6. UITableViewRowAnimationNone - Inserted rows simply appear; deleted rows simply disappear.
7. UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle - Cells are inserted and deleted with an accordion-style effect.
8. UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic - The tableView automatically chooses an appropriate animation style (available only in iOS 5 and later).

A great book on how to work with tables is [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430233486).